# Publishing SharePoint Designer Workflow 2013 from another server

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-addin

I have a situation where i have a live server say "x" where SharePoint web application and SiteCollection are setup and another sever say "y" where SharePoint designer 2013 is installed,Now i have created a designer workflow on "y" and i am publishing it to SharePoint site setup on server "x" from server "y". But i find that it is not getting published. When i go to Site settings->workflow settings i find this message "There are no SharePoint 2013 workflows associated with this site". Is this correct, what i'am doing? Any solutions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the type of the workflow?Is it Site/List or Reusable WF?Site Settings-->Workflow Settings  will only show site workflows

Comment: It is a list workflow

Answer (score 1):

Site Settings-->Workflow Settings will only show site workflows. To see list workflow , go to the List --> Workflow Settings , there you can see all the List workflows for that particular list.

Comment: i have checked that now, i get this error      workflow suspended HTTP 401 {"error_description":"The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.

x-ms-diagnostics":["3001000;reason=\"There has been an error authenticating the request.\";category=\"invalid_client\""

Comment: any ideas?I feel it is some user profile synchronization issue